# jsoup in java, парсинг скрытого текста

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup

Изучаю Java. Прохожу парсинг. Для теста взял себе авито. Подскажите как справится с телефоном? Телефон там в виде картинки, но проблему решается в мобильной версии, но телефон доступен только после клика.

При клике отправляется GET запрос:

```
GET https://m.avito.ru/ufa/gruzoviki_i_spetstehnika/prodayu_kamaz_4510_vezdehod_6h6_samosval_756789406/phone/ba8e8ac080a4dee9323783eb0df8eb55?async
```

Сам блок:

```html
<div class="person-actions">
  <a rel="nofollow" title="Телефон продавца" href="/ufa/gruzoviki_i_spetstehnika/prodayu_kamaz_4510_vezdehod_6h6_samosval_756789406/phone/ba8e8ac080a4dee9323783eb0df8eb55" class="person-action button button-solid button-blue button-large action-show-number action-link link "> 
    <span class="button-text">Показать номер</span> 
  </a>
</div>
```

Блок вытягиваю так:

```java
phone = doc.getElementsByClass("person-actions").select("a").first().html();
```

Спасибо.

---

Позже:

По рекомендации попробовал вытянуть куки и с ними вытянуть телефон, но безрезультатно. Возможно что-то делаю не так, поправьте. Код:

```
Connection.Response res = null;
        res = Jsoup.connect("https://m.avito.ru/ufa/gruzoviki_i_spetstehnika/prodayu_kamaz_4510_vezdehod_6h6_samosval_756789406")
                .execute();
    Document doc = res.parse();
    String sessionId = res.cookie("sessid");
    System.out.println(sessionId);
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

    Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect("https://m.avito.ru/ufa/gruzoviki_i_spetstehnika/prodayu_kamaz_4510_vezdehod_6h6_samosval_756789406/phone/ba8e8ac080a4dee9323783eb0df8eb55?async")
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .cookie("sessid", sessionId)
            .get();

    System.out.println(doc2.toString());
```

Консоль выдает следующее:

```
01b6fe2d900605a171df7df11847d8d9.1459841297
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  {"error":"пожалуйста, обновите страницу"}
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Пробовали запустить скачивание HTML кода по этому get запросу?

Comment: Да, пробовал. Скачивает ту же инфу, что отображает браузер, а именно: `{"error":"пожалуйста, обновите страницу"}`. Странно как-то, при вводе строки в адресную строку браузера, получаю ошибку вида JSON, а когда клацаю на самом сайте на кнопку и она отсылает этот запрос, то в фаербаге(сеть) получаю номер телефона в виде JSON

Comment: Если и в браузере нет инфы, то ничего сделать не выйдет(

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: Вот во вкладке сеть, информация есть, но не понятно как мне заставить jsoup или саму java отправить этот ГЕТ запрос и получить ответ {"phone":"1 123 123-12-12"}

Comment: `но проблему решается в мобильной версии` гениальное просто, блин, а я парсил картинку телефона :D Через QWebKit загружал страницу объявления, через js кликал на "Показать телефон", ожидал загрузки и делал парсинг картинки телефона, благо его формат всегда одинаковый. Мне кажется, автору нужно не забывать про куки

Comment: Я тоже начал с этого, но сразу стало интересно, а как звонить по такому телефону, если заходишь с мобилки, зашел глянул, а там все по другому)) Подскажете как вытянули картинку? Суть одна и та же, после нажатия появляется картинка. Куки, не думал что они играют какую-то роль, если есть целевая ГЕТ ссылка. Спасибо за подсказку, буду изучать, ранее не сталкивался.

Comment: Сначала, авито предоставляли ссылку на картинку телефона (полгода назад), неделю с чем-то запустил скрипт и обнаружил, что теперь они передавали картинку в src в base64: `src="data:image/png;base64,<image>"`

Comment: Думаю был не очень хороший сюрприз =D

Comment: Ага, немного неожиданно :)
Вот [ссылка](https://github.com/gil9red/ads_sites_parser/tree/master/avito_ru_phone_parser) на парсер. Каждое объявление парсится [этим](https://github.com/gil9red/ads_sites_parser/blob/master/avito_ru_phone_parser/avito_ad_parser.py).

Comment: Спасибо, правда питон =) но почитаю, может натолкнет на мысль.